# Custom filtering on Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

My application supports fetching data with filters. My current implementation (which works fine) is

```
Model::select($fields)->with($relations)->tap(function ($query) use ($filters) {
  // A lot of filtering logic here
  // $query->where()...... 
})->get();
```

However, I would like to move the filtering logic directly into the Model so I could just do

```
Model::select($fields)
  ->with($relations)
  ->applyFilters($filters)
  ->get();
```

I have tried to add a `filter` method to the `Model` but at that point I'm working with a `Builder` and it does not recognize my function:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::applyFilters()

Is there an easier way to do this, other than creating a new builder class  and use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! I just had to add a `scopeApplyFilters` to my `Model` class. It injects the `Builder` as the first parameter automatically, so the logic ends up looking like

```
public function scopeApplyFilters($query, $filters)
{
    // Perform filtering logic with $query->where(...);

    return $query;
}
```

Then I can just call it with `Model::applyFilters($filters);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = isset($request->name)?trim($request->name):"";
        $email = isset($request->email)?trim($request->email):"";
        $status = isset($request->status)?$request->status:"";

         $data = User::whereIn("user_type",["Branch","User"])
         ->where(function ($query)use($email) 
         {
          if($email !=''){
            $query->where('email','Like',"%{$email}%");
          }
         })->where(function ($query)use($name) 
         {
          if($name !=''){
            $query->where('name','LIKE',"%{$name}%");
          }
         })->where(function ($query)use($status) 
         {
          if($status !=''){
            $query->where('account_status',$status);
          }
         })->paginate(20);

     
        return view('all_users')->with(["data"=>$data,"name"=>$name,"email"=>$email]);
```