# Laravel Where Statement in a variable

Tags: laravel

I have a variable `$filter_value` which as below data:

```
where("document_language_id",2)->where("manufacturer_id",1)->where("manual_type_id",1)
```

I want to use that value in below query to get data:

```
$jobs = Job::$filter_values->paginate(10);
```

The problem is that I get error while doing that. So, my question is that how can I use that variable in that query?

Comment: You can not type any code in a variable to execute it. This only works for function names for example. What you can do instead is apply a scope: [Custom filtering on Eloquent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55557713/custom-filtering-on-eloquent-model)

Comment: It is confusing because I didn't use Model for such purposes.

Comment: Can you show it how to do in controller.

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible. Instead, you can use:

```
$filter_value = Job::where("document_language_id",2)->where("manufacturer_id",1)->where("manual_type_id",1);
$jobs = $filter_value->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Please remember that `$filter_value` is dynamic and it gets its value from a form when I submit it. So I want something like this `Jobs:Job::$filter_value` and it gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **query** method of **Eloquent** to get data with conditionally.

```
$jobsQuery = Job::query();

$jobsQuery->where("document_language_id",2)->where("manufacturer_id",1)->where("manual_type_id",1);

$jobsQuery->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I gives this error: Property [where("document_language_id",2)->where("manufacturer_id",1)->where("manual_type_id",1)] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

Comment: $jobs = $jobsQuery->paginate(10);

Comment: No change. It is still the same error.